# Detect and handle certain conflicts in Core Data with iCloud Sync

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, icloud

I'm trying to create a note-taking like app that uses NSPersistentCloudKitContainer and core data.

The store uses the NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy, which is fine for almost every property. For example, if the name of a file is changed on two different devices, then it's fine to use the latest value.

The problem is that the note text cannot be overridden by the latest value if it's changed on two devices at once. It needs to be detected as a conflict so the user can choose which version they want to keep.

I can replicate the behavior by turning off wifi on one device and writing content, then writing content on a different device at the same time. When I turn the wifi back on, whichever device saved the changes last completely overrides the other device's text.

What I'd like to accomplish is detect when there is a conflict of text, then create a duplicate file called "Conflicted Copy." Bonus points if someone can tell me how Apple Notes magically merges text without ever creating a conflict. I really only need a simple solution though that prevents data loss.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: If still stuck. Not had to try this yet. But I think what's needed is a custom `NSMergePolicy` and assigning that to the viewContext (or other moc instance if using).  Use a domain specific policy to trigger user resolution or property merge at a sub-string level that combines both sets of changes  to resolve all the conflicts (no inside information, but I would guess this is what Apple do).

Comment: Not been able to find anything particularly close, but this looks like an interesting read https://medium.com/@deeps_ramesh/custom-merge-policy-7badcc2f8b11 .

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a step in the right direction! I'm  surprised how little information there is on conflicts.

Comment: Yeah, definitely an unpleasant surprise.  Sometimes with stuff based on Apple's mature tech can be very old by tech standards and issue is with finding it. fwiw found a few more snippets that looked interesting with searching for "subclass NSMergePolicy" e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/ffxi6x/nsmergepolicy_subclasses/ . Adding "Objective C" to search terms might also be worth a shot as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The conflict arises when CoreData & CloudKit sync an object to the persistent store while a managed context has an updated version of the object that has not yet been saved.
Any merge policy, including a custom merge policy, is used to create a single object that will be stored in the persistent store, but you want to have both conflicting objects so that the user can choose one of them.
Thus automatic conflict resolution, including with a custom merge policy, cannot be applied.
Instead, use the default merge policy of type `error`. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmergepolicy/1690612-error) say

> If a save fails because of conflicting objects, you can find the IDs
> of those objects in error’s userInfo dictionary. Use the
> NSInsertedObjectsKey and NSUpdatedObjectsKey keys to extract the
> object IDs.

This means, you can keep the properties of the not-yet-stored conflicting object in the managed context, and re-fetch the properties of the conflicting object from the persistent store. This will overwrite the conflicting in-context version and "resolve" the conflict, but you still have now the conflicting properties and can present them to the user.
If the user selects the version in the persistent store, you are done. Otherwise update the objects properties with the kept values as required and save the context.
PS: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73209253/1987726) is for your information how to implement a custom merge policy, although it cannot be applied here, just because such info is difficult to find.

**EDIT:**
I can imagine 2 ways to have one merge policy for your "normal" objects, and the error policy for the text objects:

1. A merge policy is set for a managed context. So you could have one context with `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`, and another one with `NSErrorMergePolicy`. So if it is feasible to fetch most objects into the 1st context, but the text storing objects into the 2nd one, you could apply both conflict resolution strategies.
2. During conflict resolution, i.e. in `func resolve(optimisticLockingConflicts…`, one has to call `super.resolve(optimisticLockingConflicts:` (see my example implementation cited above). So if you set `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` to your context, but call `super` only for your "normal" objects, this merge policy would not be applied to your text objects, and you could handle the conflict by your own. **Warning**: As far as I know this is non-standard, and I am not sure what happens if you don't call super.

Comment: Is there a way to continue to use the merge policy for other objects, and use the error type on the object that stores the text? I haven't been able to try this yet but it sounds like a good idea. I have lots of other objects that would work just fine with the normal merge policy though, and I'd rather not have to create custom logic for every object.  Thanks!